# Dynamically generated opengraph meta content image width/height

Tags: javascript, facebook, metadata, facebook-opengraph

Facebook requires either preacaching a webpage (which I am unable to do) or specifying an images width and height for them to load the opengraph data properly when sharing.  My site is pulling images from MLS (pages/images stored locally) so the image sizes are different.

How can I find the image height and width and create meta content based on the results?

Comment: What’s a “MLS”?

Comment: Multiple Listing Service.  For real estate.

Comment: So what does pulling from it mean exactly? How do you access the images, and what server-side techniques do you have available?